# sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

On Amazon Workspaces I ran `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc` in order to create a file to install Docker but now after every command with sudo I run into this error

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I've seen some similar questions but couldn't solve the issue so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file).

I ran this `pkexec visudo` and it worked.