# How can I use sudo on my Amazon Workspaces linux machine?

Tags: linux, sudo

I'm installing Postgres in Amazon Workspaces linux machine. And I need to run as `sudo`.

```
After I run the command I get this response
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
[sudo] password for sb2021\'my_user':
```

I write the password and I get this error

```
sb2021\'my_user' is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Now I've seen answers where they add `user_name ALL=(ALL)  ALL` to `/etc/sudoers` but the file doesn't have write permission and I can't change it and I don't have another root user to add 'my_user' in that file.

Comment: Is the Amazon Workspaces linux machine managed by you? Or by someone else/another department?

Comment: It's not managed by me, I was invited to use it.

Comment: Then you should contact the person who manages the workspace / invited you. They should be able to enable sudo access for your user account.

Comment: @MikeDHovhannisyan - You need to request sudo access from whomever has root access (or I suppose sudo permissions).  You can't give yourself sudo permissions if you don't know root.

Comment: So there is no way to solve this without contacting management?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting](https://superuser.com/questions/1745011/sudo-no-valid-sudoers-sources-found-quitting) with important context missing. You've messed up your permissions and the easiest way to get them straight is to give up with this instance and get a new one.